# If unit A attacks unit B (which was attacking unit C) does the attack on B by A stop the attack on C by B?

Tags: diplomacy

Let's say an English fleet has orders to attack Denmark from Skagarac, with plenty of support to take it. However, a Russian fleet attacks the English fleet from the Baltic Sea, with plenty of support to take Skagarac.

Would the Russian fleet's attack take priority, preventing the English fleet from taking Denmark? Or would both moves be successful, putting Denmark in English control and Skagarac in Russian control?

Comment: BAL and SKA are not adjacent. Ry4an's answer to the question in the title is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Both attacks/moves are successful. Supports can be cut by attack from elsewhere, but moves aren't.